# ms-access VBA long sql query string line split ( with double quote inline) in editor

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a below sql query in MS-Access 2010 wghich works fine in query design window. Now I want to code it through VBA.

ACTUAL QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO MAINRESULT(EXNAME, MASTER_TICKER,MASTER_CUSIP,TL_TICKER,TL_CUSIP,FC_CUSIP,FC_TICKER)
SELECT EXC AS MY_EXC,  
SUM(IIF(MASTER_TICKER <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_MASTER_TICKER,
SUM(IIF(MASTER_CUSIP <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_MASTER_CUSIP,
SUM(IIF(TL_TICKER <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_TL_TICKER,
SUM(IIF(TL_CUSIP <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_TL_CUSIP,
SUM(IIF(FC_CUSIP <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_FC_CUSIP,
SUM(IIF(FC_TICKER <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_FC_TICKER
FROM TESTDATA
GROUP BY EXC;
```

MY VBA code snippet:

```
Dim strSQL As String
 Dim db As Database
 Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "INSERT INTO MAINRESULT(EXNAME, MASTER_TICKER,MASTER_CUSIP,TL_TICKER,TL_CUSIP,FC_CUSIP,FC_TICKER) " & _
             "SELECT EXC AS MY_EXC, " & _
             "SUM(IIF(MASTER_TICKER <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_MASTER_TICKER, " & _
             "SUM(IIF(MASTER_CUSIP <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_MASTER_CUSIP, " & _
             "SUM(IIF(TL_TICKER <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_TL_TICKER, " & _
             "SUM(IIF(TL_CUSIP <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_TL_CUSIP, " & _
             "SUM(IIF(FC_CUSIP <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_FC_CUSIP, " & _
             "SUM(IIf(FC_TICKER <> "NULL", 1, 0)) As MY_FC_TICKER " & _
             "FROM TESTDATA GROUP BY EXC;"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Unfortunately it is giving error due to that "NULL" thing in editor and always been in red. Is there any more alternate way ? Because those column names will also come dynamically from a select list box so I have to create this strSQL in a parameterized way.

Comment: Now I have manually put the whole thing in a single line still it is giving "Compile Error : Expected end of statement " near that "NULL"

Comment: Are all the fields have a value (actual text saying) "NULL" or they Null - NULL? Remember Null <> "NULL".

Comment: now I have tried to use ""NULL"" like this way but still it is not working...

Comment: @PaulFrancis ,Yes unfortunately those field values itself are "NULL" and it is not very comfortable idea to replace that with something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it beautifully work by using chr$(39) way:

```
Dim MYSTR As String
 MYSTR = "NULL"

 'teststrSQL = "SELECT EXC,FC_CUSIP FROM TESTDATA " & _
          "WHERE FC_CUSIP = " & Chr$(39) & MYSTR & Chr$(39)

 finalstrSQL = "SELECT EXC AS MY_EXC, " & _
           "SUM(IIF(MASTER_CUSIP <> " & Chr$(39) & MYSTR & Chr$(39) & " , 1, 0)) AS MY_MASTER_CUSIP, " & _
           "SUM(IIF(MASTER_TICKER <> " & Chr$(39) & MYSTR & Chr$(39) & " , 1, 0)) AS MY_MASTER_TICKER, " & _
           "SUM(IIF(TL_TICKER <> " & Chr$(39) & MYSTR & Chr$(39) & " , 1, 0)) AS MY_TL_TICKER, " & _
           "SUM(IIF(TL_CUSIP <> " & Chr$(39) & MYSTR & Chr$(39) & " , 1, 0)) AS MY_TL_CUSIP, " & _
           "SUM(IIF(FC_CUSIP <> " & Chr$(39) & MYSTR & Chr$(39) & " , 1, 0)) AS MY_FC_CUSIP, " & _
           "SUM(IIF(FC_TICKER <> " & Chr$(39) & MYSTR & Chr$(39) & " , 1, 0)) AS MY_FC_TICKER " & _
           "FROM TESTDATA GROUP BY EXC;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse NULL as a value, Null is something that cannot be compared against. You can use two variations. One is,

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "INSERT INTO MAINRESULT(EXNAME, MASTER_TICKER,MASTER_CUSIP,TL_TICKER,TL_CUSIP,FC_CUSIP,FC_TICKER) " & _
         "SELECT EXC AS MY_EXC, " & _
         "SUM(IIF(MASTER_TICKER Is Not Null, 1, 0)) AS MY_MASTER_TICKER, " & _
         "SUM(IIF(MASTER_CUSIP Is Not Null, 1, 0)) AS MY_MASTER_CUSIP, " & _
         "SUM(IIF(TL_TICKER Is Not Null, 1, 0)) AS MY_TL_TICKER, " & _
         "SUM(IIF(TL_CUSIP Is Not Null, 1, 0)) AS MY_TL_CUSIP, " & _
         "SUM(IIF(FC_CUSIP Is Not Null, 1, 0)) AS MY_FC_CUSIP, " & _
         "SUM(IIf(FC_TICKER Is Not Null, 1, 0)) As MY_FC_TICKER " & _
         "FROM TESTDATA GROUP BY EXC;"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Or you can use the IsNull function.

If the value is actually a String "NULL" then you should be comparing it using the String literal. `<> 'NULL'`.

**EDIT**

Try the following,

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "INSERT INTO MAINRESULT(EXNAME, MASTER_TICKER,MASTER_CUSIP,TL_TICKER,TL_CUSIP,FC_CUSIP,FC_TICKER) " & _
         "SELECT EXC AS MY_EXC, " & _
         "SUM(IIF(MASTER_TICKER <> 'NULL', 1, 0)) AS MY_MASTER_TICKER, " & _
         "SUM(IIF(MASTER_CUSIP <> 'NULL', 1, 0)) AS MY_MASTER_CUSIP, " & _
         "SUM(IIF(TL_TICKER <> 'NULL', 1, 0)) AS MY_TL_TICKER, " & _
         "SUM(IIF(TL_CUSIP <> 'NULL', 1, 0)) AS MY_TL_CUSIP, " & _
         "SUM(IIF(FC_CUSIP <> 'NULL', 1, 0)) AS MY_FC_CUSIP, " & _
         "SUM(IIf(FC_TICKER <> 'NULL', 1, 0)) As MY_FC_TICKER " & _
         "FROM TESTDATA GROUP BY EXC;"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: I was giving the OP the benefit of the doubt in my suggestion - but this is a perfectly valid point.

Comment: @HansUp, it might be possible that the back end is **MSSQL**, where NULL actually is displayed as a value (for the naked eye), that might have lead the OP to believe that comparing it with "NULL" as a string will work? As we know `vbNullString <> "Null"` would pass the test. This is just a stab in the dark.But I see your point.

Comment: @PaulFrancis  unfortunately the result of Is Not Null is not matching with the expected count... I am not confused about NULL as a value but in this specific case those field contains literal string "NULL" which I need to bypass while taking count and it is a pain ..... now may I get any solution

Comment: @PaulFrancis... also IsNull is giving syntax error in this case... so need other way

Comment: @PaulFrancis...  is there any way to dynamically pass the query in query design window and then getting the desired result. HansUp 's last method gives correct result in query window but not does not work through VBA

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ' instead of "

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)